# sun.audio.AudioPlayer, AudioStream won't play same sound file more than once

Tags: java

I'm trying to design a class using functionality from sun.audio.Audiplayer and sun.audio.AudioStream. I want to be able to instantiate objects with the filepath of the soundfile as the argument, then simply call a method to play the specified file. The code I have works, but is not able to play any file more than once. How can I fix this?

```
public class AudioFile {
    // attributes
    private AudioStream audioStream;

    // constructors
    public AudioFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { // improper exception-handling, to be fixed

    // declare the file path to an FileInputStream
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    // create an AudioStream from the InputStream
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
    this.audioStream = audioStream;
    }

// methods
public void playFile() {
    // start playing sound file
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException { // improper exception-handling, to be fixed

        // instantiate new AudioFile objects with path to sound files
        AudioFile correctSound = new AudioFile("sfx/correct.wav");
        AudioFile boingSound = new AudioFile("sfx/boing.wav");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            int input = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    correctSound.playFile();
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    boingSound.playFile();
                    System.out.println("Boing!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use the stream like that, streams are _forward only_ in general.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't really know much about streams, so I don't understand what you mean.
Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Streams in general can be read only once. So after the AudioStream has used the stream it cannot be used again.

A naive implementation could be like the following: creating and opening a stream each time the audio is played.

```
public class AudioFile {
    // attributes
    private String filePath;

    // constructors
    public AudioFile(String filePath) { // improper exception-handling, to be fixed
        // declare the file path to an FileInputStream
        this.filePath=filePath;
    }

    // methods
    public void playFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
        // Put open of FileInputStream in a try to be sure to close it
        try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath)){
            // create an AudioStream from the InputStream
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            this.audioStream = audioStream;

            // start playing sound file
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        }
    }
}
```

If the file are small, a byte buffer can be used to keep the audio in memory, but if the file is small, there is also little to gain to store it in memory.